# Why is there a conflict in my constraint when I'm Inserting using TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table set up using TSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE NORM_TRADE_AMOUNT
(
SOURCE_ID INT NULL
, SOURCE_STATE_ID INT NULL
, DESTINATION_ID INT NULL
, DESTINATION_STATE_ID INT NULL
, CONSTRAINT C_TRADE_IMPORT
    CHECK( SOURCE_ID IS NULL OR SOURCE_STATE_ID IS NULL )
, CONSTRAINT C_TRADE_EXPORT
    CHECK( DESTINATION_ID IS NULL OR DESTINATION_STATE_ID IS NULL )
, CONSTRAINT C_ALL_TRADE
    CHECK(          (( SOURCE_ID IS NULL OR SOURCE_STATE_ID IS NULL ) OR ( DESTINATION_ID IS NULL OR DESTINATION_STATE_ID IS NULL ))
            AND NOT (( SOURCE_ID IS NULL OR SOURCE_STATE_ID IS NULL ) AND ( DESTINATION_ID IS NULL OR DESTINATION_STATE_ID IS NULL ))
    )
, CONSTRAINT FK_SOURCE FOREIGN KEY (SOURCE_ID) REFERENCES NORM_COUNTRY(COUN_F_ID)
, CONSTRAINT FK_SOURCE_STATE FOREIGN KEY (SOURCE_STATE_ID) REFERENCES NORM_STATE(STATE_F_ID)
, CONSTRAINT FK_DESTINATION FOREIGN KEY (DESTINATION_ID) REFERENCES NORM_COUNTRY(COUN_F_ID)
, CONSTRAINT FK_DESTINATION_STATE FOREIGN KEY (DESTINATION_STATE_ID) REFERENCES NORM_STATE(STATE_F_ID)
)
```

And I'm trying to insert data such as:

```
INSERT INTO NORM_TRADE_AMOUNT
VALUES(NULL,6033001,NULL,NULL)
,(NULL,6033002,NULL,NULL)
,(NULL,6033004,NULL,NULL)
,(NULL,6033005,NULL,NULL)
```

I think have the table set up so that either I have at least one of the four column has data, while having data in `DESTINATION_ID` or `DESTINATION_STATE_ID` but never both, or having data in `SOURCE_ID` or `SOURCE_STATE_ID` but never both, but never having all four of them being `NULL`.
Yet when I try to insert my data, I get a error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "C_ALL_TRADE". The conflict occurred in database "RT_AGR_STG_DW", table "dbo.NORM_TRADE_AMOUNT".
```

Am I doing something wrong logically? or is the syntax off?

Comment: Your C_ALL_TRADE will never let you insert anything. All tests I tried failed to insert any combination of values. Any reason in particular you are forcing yourself into this situation?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve from CHECK constraint "C_ALL_TRADE"?

Comment: Im trying to make sure that it's not all empty mostly, nor data in both `DESTINATION_ID` and `DESTINATION_STATE_ID`

Comment: @facsasd Is this data getting inserted by an application? An ETL process? Enforce the logic elsewhere?

Comment: @dfundako I'm just manually doing it all right now

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you should delete `C_ALL_TRADE` constraint. It already has in it `C_TRADE_IMPORT` and `C_TRADE_EXPORT`. The rest of the check prevents you from inserting anything.

```
AND NOT (( SOURCE_ID IS NULL OR SOURCE_STATE_ID IS NULL ) AND ( DESTINATION_ID IS NULL OR DESTINATION_STATE_ID IS NULL ))
```

This prevents `( SOURCE_ID IS NULL OR SOURCE_STATE_ID` to be `NULL` and `( DESTINATION_ID IS NULL OR DESTINATION_STATE_ID` TO BE `NULL`, but at the same time you want them to be `NULL` (previous checks).

Comment: oh then maybe i wrote it wrong? I'm trying to have data, but not too much

Comment: If you want to have data in (SOURCE_ID  or SOURCE_STATE_ID) and in (DESTINATION_ID OR DESTINATION_STATE_ID) then IMHO C_ALL_TRADE is unnecessary.

Comment: `C_ALL_TRADES` is to assure that there is still data in one of the lines

Answer (score 0):

`CONSTRAINT C_TRADE_IMPORT CHECK( SOURCE_ID IS NULL OR SOURCE_STATE_ID IS NULL )` ensures that you don't put non-NULL values in *both* columns. Similarly with `CONSTRAINT C_TRADE_EXPORT CHECK( DESTINATION_ID IS NULL OR DESTINATION_STATE_ID IS NULL )`.

You can take advantage of the columns all having the same data type (`int`): `Coalesce( SOURCE_ID, SOURCE_STATE_ID, DESTINATION_ID, DESTINATION_STATE_ID ) is not NULL` will be *true* if at least one of the four columns has a non-NULL value. Combined with the first two constraints it will ensure that either one or two values are not NULL.